# Ext 4.2, Sencha Cmd 3 + deftjs - Can't build a working applicaton

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, sencha-command, deftjs

I've upgraded my build tools for an ext + deftjs application from Sencha SDK to Sencha Cmd (v3).
In doing so I also upgraded Ext to 4.2 and Deft to Ext 0.8. I initially had a problem with Ext.onReady() not being fired, resulting in my viewControllers not being instantiated from their corresponding views. However, I've [fixed that](https://github.com/deftjs/DeftJS/wiki/F.A.Q.#how-do-i-enable-logging-within-deftjs) and the application is now working in dev mode

I'm now trying to build the application using the commands `sencha app refresh` and `sencha app build` but the built application isn't loading at all.

Again, the my ViewControllers aren't being instantiated. The deft classes and the viewcontrollers have been added to all-classes.js by the build tools. (The Deft classes are first in the file + view controllers further down)

**sencha.cfg** contains the following classpath:

```
app.classpath=${app.dir}/Deft,${app.dir}/ux,${app.dir}/uvd,${app.dir}/app,${app.dir}/inj.js,${app.dir}/app.js
```

**inj.js** contains my loader declarations:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled:true,
    paths:{
        'UVd': 'uvd',
        'Ext.ux' : 'ux',
        'Deft' : 'Deft',
        'FM' : 'app',
        'Ext': 'ext/src'
    }
});

Ext.syncRequire([
    "Ext.Component",
    "Ext.ComponentManager",
    "Ext.ComponentQuery",
    'Deft.mixin.Controllable',
    'Deft.mixin.Injectable',
    'Deft.Injector'
]);
```

My main **Viewport** is the first view to be instantiated, and contains the following declarations:

```
Ext.define('FM.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    requires: [
        'FM.controller.Viewport'
    ],
    // DI
    controller: 'FM.controller.Viewport'
```

My dev **index.html** looks like this:

```
    <!-- <x-compile> -->
      <!-- <x-bootstrap> -->
        <script src="ext/ext-all.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
      <!-- </x-bootstrap> -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="inj.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
    <!-- </x-compile> -->
```

Does anyone have any idea why the view controllers wouldn't be instantiated in a compiled version of the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ant task will be like that . Check in the extjs folder you have this folders (resources, src)

```
<x-sencha-command>
            -sdk 
                ${basedir}/WebContent/extjs
            compile
                -classpath=WebContent/app.js,WebContent/utilities.js,WebContent/app
                page
                    --yui
                    --in=WebContent/index.html
                    --out=WebContent/build/index.html
        </x-sencha-command>
```